# Horizontal Center Items inside VariableSizedWrapGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a VariableSizedWrapGrid, with buttons as items:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LinkTemplate" x:DataType="local:LinkWeb">
            <Button Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="15,15,15,15" Click="Button_Click" >
                <Button.Content>                
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageLink}" Margin="8,8,8,8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="{Binding HeightImage}" Width="{Binding WidthImage}"/>                        
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>            
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

...

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="imageContent" ItemsSource="{Binding Enlaces}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LinkTemplate}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The VariableSizedWrapGrid shows two items per row, but the items appears aligned to the left, as you can see:

[image]

I need the VariableSizedWrapGrid shows the items centered in his content, like this:

[image]

Any idea about how I can achieve this?

**EDIT**

I've tried center the ScrollViewer, and, yes, items are "a little more centered", because VariableSizedWrapGrid inside ScrollViewer is centered, but, inside VariableSizedWrapGrid items float to the left, so items are not centered as you can see in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Why not simply center the ScrollViewer or the ItemsControl within it?

Comment: I've tried center the ScrollViewer, and, yes, items are "a little more centered", because VariableSizedWrapGrid inside ScrollViewer is centered, but, inside VariableSizedWrapGrid items float to the left, so they are not centered. I'm going to update question to show that. Thank you

Comment: @CarlosTI Have you solved your question by my solution? If you have any other concern regarding this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the HorizontalChildrenAlignment property value of VariableSizedWrapGrid as `Center`. It should work.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Center" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thx! I was testing another strange behavior, if I put more elements than the configuration MaximumRowsOrColumns allows (in this case "2", because I was trying 2 columns, and variable number of rows) the variablesizegrid goes crazy and the Items aling to left. In your example, if you add more elements, the items are still centered?